# How to remove product from collection By custom product attribute

Tags: magento-1.8

Friends,
Facing the problem while filtering the product collection.
I have get my product collection.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

and for every product i have custom attribute called product_creator_id [code].

So I need to filter the product based on the product_creator_id.

I am Using following code to get, but Its not affecting the list

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('product_creator_id', array('in' => $productCreatorIds));
```

Any suggestion for this

Comment: What is `$currentStoreId` in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an 'in' filter, you will need to provide an array:

```
$productCreatorIdsToFilter = array(1,2,3);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('product_creator_id', array('in' => $productCreatorIdsToFilter));
```

Comment: you mean $productCreatorIdsToFilter must be an array?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried like this?

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('style', 'brass');
```

This will give you all the products which have an attribute style with value brass.

When you want to filter data from EAV collection you use addAttributeToFilter, and when you want to filter data from Flat table collection you use addFieldToFilter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter by a specific value do this:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('product_creator_id', $value);
```

If you want multiple values use what @mpaepper described.

Comment: Yes, I tried both but I am not getting filter product collection,It is same list in Grid,